# Entering password characters in JMeter based on captcha request

Tags: jmeter

Are there any techniques that can be used to log in to a website with JMeter, when you are asked for the x,y,z characters of the password?

edit: a little more info: I'm recording HTTP requests, and for our local environment you just login with the password, which works fine. For the "live" site it asks for random different characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jmeter testcases which can handle captcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964358/jmeter-testcases-which-can-handle-captcha)

Comment: similar, in that it appears to be something that we can't automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement what you want you have to proceed this way:

- Extract from the page that ask the 3 characters using either [Regular_Expression_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) , [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). This will create for example 2 variables start and end
- Then add a [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) using Groovy to extract the characters required from the password, example:

> ```
> def start = vars["start"];
> def end = vars["end"];
> def password = vars["password"]; // This can come from a CSV or be hard coded if it does not change
> vars.put("passwordExtract", password.substring(start, end));
> ```

- You can then use ${passwordExtract} to input the value in next request

Comment: The password isn't random, it's always the same. But each time I login I get asked for different characters, e.g. the 1st, 3rd and 4th. Next time in it might be the 2nd, 5th and 6th characters that are asked for.

Comment: You mean there is a question asking you this in the application ? a kind of captcha ?

Comment: Yes. So when we run it locally it asks for the password, so I can just send that in the POST. But when it is deployed it asks for 3 characters from the password - a different 3 each time.

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. We ended up with a BeanShell PreProcessor, and the logic is slightly different (it doesn't want a substring of the password, it wants certain characters).

Comment: Thanks for feedback but you should really not use Beanshell as it does not scale correctly. Use Groovy and check "Cache...." instead. Groovy outperforms beanshell by at least a factor of 10

Comment: thanks again, it does look pretty slow, I will try to convert the BeanShell